# How do I display html coming from a json list in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

having a json set of information like

```
[
    {
    "title":"Title 1",
    "description":"<p>Some HTML</p>"
    },
    {
    "title":"Title 2",
    "description":"<p>Some HTML</p><p>More HTML</p>"
    }
]
```

how do I show the html in my template. Currently the html is not decoded.
I tried with the code below but it doesn't work.

```
{{item.title}}
<div data-ng-bind-html='item.description'></div>
```

Controller looks like

```
var searchApp = angular.module('searchApp', ['ngSanitize']);

searchApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('search-json').success(function(json) {
    $scope.item = json.data;
    $scope.orderProp = 'title';
  });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: if json.data is an array of objects you have to write {{item[0].title}} or use ng-repeat

Comment: That's what I do, problem is item.description comes out as <p>Some HTML</p> instead of the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add ngSanitize , inject $sce and then in js

```
   $scope.getHtml = function(html) {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)    
   }
```

and in html

```
<span>{{item.title}}</span>
<div data-ng-bind-html="getHtml(item.description)"> <div>
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work but I think that for version 1.3 you don't need the getHtml anymore. Just adding $sce seems to fix the problem for me. Not sure why